# add elements in list on end scroll angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a requirement which is to display a list of elements on one line, allow user to scroll, and when he scrolls to the end, call a function to add elements in this list.

I managed to display elements on a line, call function on end of scroll, add elements in the list, but the problem is, my view doesn't display the new elements, and the end of scroll doesn't work anymore.

I am using angularJS, what I need is basically an infinite horizontal scrolling.

Here is my code :
 - html :

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div ng-repeat="t in test" class="content">
    qqq
  </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.timeline {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

js :

```
app.controller('timelineController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.test = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $scope.test.push(i);
    }

    $(function () {
        $('.timeline').scroll(function () {
            if ($('.timeline').scrollLeft() == ($scope.test.length * 200 - 500)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    $scope.test.push(i);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

I use jquery for that, but I would rather use angularJS. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that could solve my issue.

here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b67x9pog/

All ideas are more than welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update is happening outside of the Angular digest cycle, so it's not aware of the update to $scope. You need to wrap the update in `$scope.$apply()` to let Angular know about the changes.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('timelineController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.test = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $scope.test.push(i);
    }

    $(function() {
        $('.timeline').scroll(function() {
            if ($('.timeline').scrollLeft() == ($scope.test.length * 200 - 500)) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {  // <--- $scope.$apply() added here
                    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        $scope.test.push(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}]);
```

In this example, you'll also want to add a `track by` to the `ng-repeat` to avoid issues with duplicate keys:

```
<div class="timeline">
    <div ng-repeat="t in test track by $index" class="content">
        qqq
    </div>
</div>
```